# Best way to read log file taking date as parameter and returning logs as Rest API

Tags: java, spring

I have a requirement of reading log file accepting date and log level(optional) as parameter(Spring Web Services) and sending back to customer, is there any way excluding manual Read Write operation to accomplish it.

Comment: What have you tried? In what form do you have the logs? Plaintext file or db Table ... What is your definition of "**manual** Read Write operation"?

Comment: My file is in form of plaintext file with yyyy-MM-dd(date) starting string for each line of logs. Manual Read Write means i have written simple java program which will read line by line and compare with user defined date.

Comment: That's really suboptimal if you want to provide a filter for date. For each request, you'll have to go through the log line-by-line and add to your result. If I were to do it, I'd change logging to log into a DB table. So filtering for Date (and pagination) would be as easy as constructing the according sql-query. Of course - this is not an option if you cannot change that.

Comment: Yes @Fildor i know that, we came to conclusion that date should not be older than a  week.

Comment: The point is: if you only have a plain text file, You'll always have to "manually read write" somehow. Even if you let the filter only be 1 week max, you will still have to open the whole (big?) logfile. Of course, you could use dayly rolling logfiles to minimize overhead. But still you have to parse each line if you also want to filter for log level. Of course, you could configure logging to write level-filtered daily rolling files. But this again would need that you can in fact change the logging config.

Comment: By the way: Which logging framework is in use? Log4j? Slf4j/logback? commons ?